# creating tagclouds in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index in es with the following mapping:

```
"mappings": {

            "properties": {
                "date":{"type":"date","format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s||yyyy-MM-dd H:m:ss||yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"},
                "time":{ "type": "text"},
                "frame_id": {"type":"integer"},
                "camera_id":{"type":"integer"},
                "path":{"type":"text"},
                "objects" : {"type": "nested", 
                             "properties": {
                                            "class":    { "type": "text" ,"fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          } },
                                            "confidence": { "type": "float"  },
                                             "coordinates":{ "type": "nested" ,
                                                             "properties": { "x" :{"type":"float"},
                                                                             "y" :{"type":"float"},
                                                                             "w" :{"type":"float"},
                                                                             "h" :{"type":"float"}
                                                             }  }
        
                                            }
                
            }
        
    }
}
```

and I am trying to make Tag clouds in kibana on field "objects.class" but I am not able to see "object.class" field in visualize=>create=>field .
Please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the visualizations in Kibana do not work on nested fields.

Support for nested fields in visualizations is [in the works](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1084#issuecomment-585178079) but not released yet.

Comment: So, is there any other way to do so?

Comment: You were right it dose not works with nested mapping hence when i changed the mapping it did work fine. Thanks

Comment: Nested might be necessary depending on what you want to do, but if it works the way you want without nested, then ok.